# Datagridview checkbox checked when clicking the cell

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, checked

I handle my checkbox click event with the *CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged*. What I want to be able to do is handle the same event when I click the **cell** that contains the checkbox too, i.e. when I click the cell, check the checkbox and call the DirtyStateChanged. Using the following code does not help much, it does not even call the *CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged*. I've run out of ideas.

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly != true)
    {       
          //option 1
          (dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value = true;
          //option 2
          DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbc = (dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell);
          cbc.Value = true;
          //option 3
          dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: is this XAML? that would be a better tag for the question than [cell] and [checked]

Comment: Why would this question get a minus vote?

Comment: The downvote is because there are a lot of opinionated idiots at SO who think that's the best way to add value.

Comment: I agree, these idiots should rather give a better solution, or, at least a valid reason along with a up/down vote instead of being biased.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Bioukh points out, you must call `NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true)` to trigger your event handler.  However, adding that line will no longer update your checked state.  To finalize your checked state change *on click* we'll add a call to `RefreshEdit`.  This will work to toggle your cell checked state when the cell is clicked, but it will also make the first click of the actual checkbox a bit buggy.  So we add the `CellContentClick` event handler as shown below and you should be good to go.

---

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

  if (cell != null && !cell.ReadOnly)
  {
    cell.Value = cell.Value == null || !((bool)cell.Value);
    this.dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
    this.dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
  }
}
```

---

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  this.dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I get the 'specified cast is not valid' exception: (bool)cell.value

Comment: @Jnr What is the value of the cell if not `True` or `False`?

Comment: That's a good question and I did not mention that the datagridview is data bound. So the value is DBNull. Instead of using the cast to bool, I used dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = true;
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help! Good job figuring out that fix.

Comment: Works great. You can get rid of the "cell.Value == null ||" since its guaranteed to not be null at that line.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want :

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly != true)
    {       
        dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = true;
        dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView3_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView3.Columns["Select"].Index)//checking for select click
        {
            dataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value = dataGridView3.CurrentCell.FormattedValue.ToString() == "True" ? false : true;
            dataGridView3.RefreshEdit();
        }
    }
```

These Changes had Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach to OhBeWise solution with a static function in `HelperClass`

```
public static void DataGrid_CheckBoxCellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dataGrid = sender as DataGridView;
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = dataGrid?.CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

    if(cell != null && !cell.ReadOnly)
    {
        cell.Value = cell.Value == null || !(bool)cell.Value;
        dataGrid.RefreshEdit();
        dataGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    }
}
```

In your code behind

`dataGridView1.CellClick += HelperClass.DataGrid_CheckBoxCellClick;`

Answer (score 0):

Code bellow is not necessary :-)

```
if(dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly != true)
```

You can write it simplier:

```
if(!dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
```