# DataGridView value doesn't change when calling CellContentClicked event

Tags: c#, datagridview

My expectation: `Is Wash` and `Is Return` are `ComboBox` columns; when I click `Is Wash`, I intend to change `Is Return` to `true`.

This is my `DataGridView`:
[image: valid XHTML]

I tried to use `CellContentClick` and `CellClick`

Below is my function:

```
private void dtGridViewLoan_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        return;
    if (dtGridViewLoan.SelectedRows[0].Cells["is_wash"].Value != DBNull.Value)
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dtGridViewLoan.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["is_wash"].Value))
        {
            dtGridViewLoan.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["is_return"].Value = true;
        }
}
```

In the end, no matter how I change the `ComboBox` value, the data itself keeps returning `false` even it is `true`. Please help.

Comment: question is not clear please elaborate what you want

Comment: Another [option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29418616/3773066) to TaW's answer (which is already quite efficient).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

great answer by taw, thanks for your help. Your answer is wrong because i already used the method that u asked me to use, but the result is still same.

In the end, i realize what wrong with it is because when i tick the check box, the column itself doesnt call the cell value changed method. because when i  enable editing, when u tick the checkbox, the data grid view will enter 'edit mode' which the cell value changed method only be called when u exit the column ( please see the row header of the picture, the picture showed the pencil icon). I will try not to use enable editing for this case. thanks for help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj1v1.png

Comment: It doesn't enter  `CellValueChanged` __until__ the data are commited. But it __does immediately__ enter the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event, where you can commit the data. This is tested and works fine, as it should, coming directly from MSDN..

Comment: You should accept TaW's answer. It's correct and a good solution. You might have done something wrong when you tried it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with checking `DataGridViewCheckboxCells` in the `CellClick` is that they **don't yet have** the new values.  This makes more sense for other cell types, which may have to go through more or less complicated validation routines more or less successfully, but we have to live with it.

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you have two options:

> Typically, check box cell values are intended either for storage, like
>   any other data, or for performing bulk operations. If you want to
>   respond immediately when users click a check box cell, you can handle
>   the DataGridView.CellClick event, but this event occurs before the
>   cell value is updated. If you need the new value at the time of the
>   click, one option is to calculate what the expected value will be
>   based on the current value. Another approach is to commit the change
>   immediately, and handle the DataGridView.CellValueChanged event to
>   respond to it. To commit the change when the cell is clicked, you must
>   handle the DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event. In the
>   handler, if the current cell is a check box cell, call the
>   DataGridView.CommitEdit method and pass in the Commit value.

I find the 1st approach seemingly simpler but rather hacky.

Here is an example of the second, somewhat cleaner approach:
First we immediatly commit any checkbox clicks:

```
// add the event handler to the grid view
dtGridViewLoan.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += 
               new EventHandler(dtGridViewLoan_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);

private void dtGridViewLoan_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dtGridViewLoan.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) 
        dtGridViewLoan.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Now this code can be used to work with the new checkbox values:

```
private void dtGridViewLoan_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // ..
    if (dtGridViewLoan.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "is_wash") 
       { your code here...  }
    // ..
}
```

Comment: The `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` way is way better than the calculation approach. Just add 1 more handler, "flush" the changes out and deal with them as you usually would. Even if it's called "dirty" it's far cleaner than the other one.